# Python sqlite; pull REAL values as float and use for calculation, pull TEXT as str and concatenate

Tags: python, sqlite

Im consistently struggling with doing anything with outputs from sqlite, for example I have selected some REAL values from one of my columns, by default they come out in the form:

```
[(0.0,), (10.0,), (2.5,), (15.0,), (1.25,), (0.0,), (0.0,), (1.25,), (0.0,), (None,)]
```

So where a= that data, now I want to sum the values, but I cant:

```
b = sum(a)
```

because it tells me I cant sum on integers and tuples (unlcear why its saying int in the error not float, but anyway I can understand why tuples isnt OK).

I see we can do this in sqlite:

```
a = c.execute('select SUM(values) from TABLE').fetchall()
```

but that still doesnt give me a float, it comes in the form:

```
[(30.0,)]
```

So its simple, I just want my results from sqlite as a list of floats when they are REAL, or as a list of strings when they are TEXT.  This seems like a standard request, but I cant find clear examples of how its done anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any TEXT values in your example.

Comment: If you try `a[0][0]` you will get `30.0` so it is a float value.

Comment: Ok so how do I get the list of values before the sum, I need that extracted too.

Comment: I also have TEXT and cant extract it as a list of strings, its the exact same issue, just with a string rather yhan a float

Answer (score 0):

Queries returns their results in the form of a table, i.e., as a list of rows, each of which is a tuple containing the column values.
This is true even if the query returns only a single value.

If extracting the value is too cumbersome for your, use a helper function:

```
def query_single_value(db, sql, params=()):
    return db.execute(sql, params).fetchone()[0]
```

To extract all the values from a single column, use `zip`:

```
def query_single_column(db, sql, params=()):
    return zip(*db.execute(sql, params).fetchall())[0]
```

or a list comprehension:

```
def query_single_column(db, sql, params=()):
    return [row[0] for row in db.execute(sql, params)]
```

Comment: I thought this worked, but it still gives a tuple:
(30.0,)

Comment: Which one are you talking about?

Comment: the column comes out as: (0.0, 10.0, 2.5, 15.0, 1.25, 0.0, 0.0, 1.25, 0.0, None)

Comment: Ok your third option gives [0.0, 10.0, 2.5, 15.0, 1.25, 0.0, 0.0, 1.25, 0.0, None] for the range, so I think that is list that I can do arithmetic on, right?

Comment: No, it doesnt allow it

Comment: It's a normal list. I'd guess `None` is a problem.

Comment: Yeah I did a list = list[:-1] to take out the None.  But I was still getting problems with errors about nonetype and int when trying to multiply the list.